# Using lookup with group in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a bunch of records in this format on mongodb

```
[
  {_id: 1, date:'2023-07-28',sales:1,ad_id:1,status: 'Active'},
  {_id: 2 , date:'2023-07-29',sales:2,ad_id:1,status: 'Active'},
   {_id: 3, date: '2023-07-30',sales: 4,ad_id:1,status: 'Paused'},
   {_id: 4, date: '2023-07-30',sales: 4,ad_id:2,status: 'Paused'},

]
```

Now if I want data from date `2023-07-28` to `2023-07-29` . I want sales to be summed but I want the status from latest record that is of `2023-07-30`. So In the end I want result something like this
`{'ad_id': 1, sales: 3, status: 'Paused'}`.

On mysql it would be something like this

```
 with ad as (
 SELECT sum(sales) as totalSales,ad_id from table_name
    where date >= '2023-07-28' and date <= '2023-07-29'
 group by ad_id 
)
SELECT * from ad left join (
   SELECT id,ad_id,status from table_name where id in (
       select max(id) from table_name group by ad_id
   )
) t on t.ad_id = ad.ad_id
```

Comment: If I understand the query you want, and all the data is in a single collection, there is no need for `"$lookup"`.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `"date"` is stored as a string rather than a BSON date.  Is there a guarantee that all `"date"` string values are formatted as `"YYYY-MM-DD"`?  Is there a guarantee that the maximum `"_id"` for a specific `"ad_id"` corresponds to the _greatest_ `"date"`?

Comment: This is just an sample of data yes all ad_id corresponds to the date

Comment: Why is the answer by @rickhg12hs unsatisfied? Is there a condition it does not meet?

Comment: @nimrodserok My answer below satisfies the question, and the OP had some different/additional requirements (not in the question above) that are in the comments and chat.  I gave modified pipelines there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ad_id",
      "statusObj": {
        // get the last status
        "$max": {
          "date": "$date",
          "_id": "$_id",
          "status": "$status"
        }
      },
      "sales": {
        "$sum": {
          // only sum sales in date range
          "$cond": [
            {"$and": [
                {"$gte": ["$date", "2023-07-28"]},
                {"$lte": ["$date", "2023-07-29"]}
              ]
            },
            "$sales",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // output desired fields
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "ad_id": "$_id",
      "sales": 1,
      "status": "$statusObj.status"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SkdB5LNEgGk).

Comment: Wouldn't this give all result if there is an data for `2023-07-30` for ad_id:2

Comment: @ashokpoudel I don't understand your comment.  Perhaps you could modify the [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SkdB5LNEgGk) to demonstrate a problem?

Comment: Here is the new playground link https://mongoplayground.net/p/p0M1qYvGyur .  If you take data from 28 to 29 . It should not show data for 30. ad_id: 2 has only data for 30

Comment: @ashokpoudel So, if the sales during the dates of interest are `0`, then you do wish to see that?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to see ad_id:2 at all . Not with the value 0

Comment: @ashokpoudel  That's a simple `"$match"` stage after the `"$group"` stage.  Here's a link to the [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hjJv7fWGDfV) with that modification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254839/discussion-between-ashok-poudel-and-rickhg12hs).

Answer (score 1):

**I'll give a summary of what the following code is doing:**

1. using [`facet`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AIe86prkqbA) to create two difference aggregates named as `salesSum` and `recentStatus`
2. In `salesSum` we are filtering on the date, then grouping on `ad_id` column and then extracting the `sales` info from it
3. In `recentStatus` we are grouping on `ad_id` and figuring out the max of `_id` column through grouping, then filtering it on the `maxId` to get the recent `status` using [`$push: "$$ROOT"`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AIe86prkqbA)
4. Then doing a kind of cartesian product on `salesSum` and `recentStatus` tables using `$unwind`
5. Then filtering them on `ad_id`

---

**Code:**

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      salesSum: [
        {
          // filters on date
          $match: {
            date: {
              $gte: "2023-07-28",
              $lte: "2023-07-29",
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        {
          // groups on ad_id and gets sum of sales
          $group: {
            _id: "$ad_id",
            sales: {
              $sum: "$sales",
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        {
          // select specific cols
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            ad_id: "$_id",
            sales: 1,
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      recentStatus: [
        {
          // group on ad_id, get maxId
          // assuming maximum ID is associated with latest entry
          $group: {
            _id: "$ad_id",
            maxId: {
              $max: "$_id",
              
            },
            // pushes all related data which have ad_id values as the same as grouped value
            items: {
              $push: "$$ROOT",
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$items",
          
        },
        {
          // filter items based on maxId
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$maxId",
                "$items._id"
              ],
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            ad_id: "$_id",
            status: "$items.status",
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$salesSum",
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$recentStatus",
    
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$salesSum.ad_id",
          "$recentStatus.ad_id"
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ad_id: "$salesSum.ad_id",
      sales: "$salesSum.sales",
      status: "$recentStatus.status",
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

[Try it on Mongo PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AIe86prkqbA)

Comment: Using $facet as the first stage will prohibit the use of an index for the query.  This might be better as 2 separate queries run from the client, and then combined on the client side

Comment: Combining two query creates problems with pagination and sorting which I want to add later